# On Ignite 2.8.1 upgrade startup is crashing with NPE for cassandra persistence

Tags: cassandra, persistence, ignite

I was using ignite 2.8.0 and integration with cassandra was working fine. With upgrade to ignite 2.8.1, ignite startup is failing with message : `Failed to validate cache configuration. Cache store factory is not serializable.` Underlying exception is Null Pointer Exception.

```java
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start processor: GridProcessorAdapter []

Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to validate cache configuration. Cache store factory is not serializable. Cache name

Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.<init>

  at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.persistence.PersistenceSettings.readObject(PersistenceSettings.java:533)
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.<init>(Collections.java:1028)
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.<init>(Collections.java:1304)
        at java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList(Collections.java:1289)
        at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.persistence.PersistenceSettings.readObject(PersistenceSettings.java:533)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Answer (score 1):

I can see that there was the [Cassandra-related ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-12863) that brought a new code and most likely caused the issue.

The new ticket is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-13431

Comment: My bad, I'm going to take a look at it. Realistically, the fix will be in 2.10